# C# How to turn String with Carriage Return symbols in to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am calling some external method that returns a string like this.

```
"[\r\n  \"0\",\r\n  \"1\",\r\n  \"2\"\r\n]"
```

How do I turn this in to an Array with the values 1,2,3 ?

Should I be trying to split/substring methods to do this, or is there some kind of built in .net method that can do this?

I have tried,

```
string theStringResult = Class.ExternalMethod();
theStringResult.ToArray()
```

Comment: Did you try using split?

Comment: That looks like JSON to me. If it is, why not use an actual JSON parser?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Not yet, I know I can do it using split but I wanted to know if there is a built in .net way of doing so.

Comment: @AyoAdesina I am a little confused by the example provided as the return string. are the brackets included in the returned string? cause then it looks like a JSON string array

Comment: @Nkosi Yes the brackets are included, I have no control over the external method and what it returns I have to work with that string.

Comment: @Blorgbeard how?

Comment: The most popular one is https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: @AyoAdesina Then go with the JSON array route. NewtonSoft Json.Net `string[] array = JsonConver.DeserializeObject<string[]>(theStringResult)`

Comment: @Nkosi You started with a comment that the question wasn't good enough, but you gave me the answer that works - Thank you. You can vote the question back up now :-) and answer the question I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: @AyoAdesina I did not vote on the question. And my initial comment is a standard comment to help you improve your question. In its initial state the question was unclear, and then you updated it. Once clear I would then remove my comment.

Comment: @Nkosi ok cool - if you answer the question I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: @AyoAdesina this is what we typically call an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Nkosi :-) I like you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The returned string appears to be a JSON array made up of strings.

The line breaks are part of a pretty print version of the JSON string which,  when not escaped, would look like this...

```js
[
  "0",
  "1",
  "2"
]
```

You can use Newtonsoft's Json.Net to parse and deserialize the returned string into a strongly typed object.

```
string theStringResult = Class.ExternalMethod();
string[] array = JsonConver.DeserializeObject<string[]>(theStringResult);
```

The above should produce the desired result

Answer (score 0):

The method you're looking for is `String.Split`.  It takes a single character as a parameter and returns an array of pieces split wherever that character is found.

In your case you have two characters (`"\r\n"`) so either you split and post-process the array, or you replace the pair with a single character and then split.

In code it looks like this:

```
string source = "\r\n0\r\n1\r\n2\r\n";
string parts = source.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Split('\n');
```

The resultant array is `["0", "1", "2"]`.

---

Oh, that's a literal JSON string... that wasn't entirely clear on first viewing.

If the array is fairly consistent you *could* do string manipulation, but it's not ideal.

Add the `NewtonSoft.Json` NuGet package to your project and use the following:

```
string source = "[\r\n  \"0\",\r\n  \"1\",\r\n  \"2\"\r\n]";
string[] parts = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(source);
```

Same output as above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
string Originalstring = "[\r\n  \"0\",\r\n  \"1\",\r\n  \"2\"\r\n]";
string[] result = Originalstring.Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This should split a string that has a carriage return into an array and remove any empty entries